# how to interact with my exe file using python

Tags: python

Problem:
I am a beginner in programming and I learned Python because of my scientific research. I wanted to run some python modules like numpy, sklearn, etc. (in machine learning) on ironpython, but I couldn't find a good way...

Question:
**I thought of exporting an exe output from the python code and programming it in a way that I could interact with on ironpython.** That means getting inpout and output.**
Is this possible with subprocess? 
or Is there a better way?

Comment: Your question is too general. I advise you to check the official Python documentation and follow the instructions, it is a good and very helpful documentation. If you have a problem after trying you may ask again, it would be easier for people to provide help in that case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can achieve this in Python shell by using subprocess. For input you have to add input at *my_input_here* in below codes.

You can store the output in p by following method:

```
p = subprocess.check_output("myfile.exe my_input_here", shell=True).strip()
```

or you can also use subprocess like this:

```
p = subprocess.Popen(['myfile.exe', 'my_input_here'],stdin=subprocess.PIPE,stdout=subprocess.PIPE,stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
```